# Example of oscillatory sequence with sum alternating between $\pm \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am looking for an example of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ whose sum oscillates between $\pm \infty$. Is it possible to use Alternating series theorem to deduce that this behaviour. The theorem says that if $\lim u_n\ne 0$, then the series oscillates. But it does not say whether it is a finite oscillation.

Comment: $$a_{2^k+i}=(-1)^k\qquad (k\geqslant0)\quad (0\leqslant i<2^k)$$

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for a sequence where the $nth$ partial sum $s_n$ approaches both $\infty$ and $-\infty,$ at different $n$ values?  Or an alternating sequence where $|s_n| < \infty,$ but alternates?

Comment: @Merkh: Your first interpretation.