# Radius and interval of convergence for $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n^2}}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n^2}}{2^n}$

I shall find the series radius and interval of convergence. I tried to use the ratio test and the nth root test to check the absolute convergence but failed. Please give me a hint how to approach this series.

Comment: Some hints: We have $|x^{n^2}| \leq |x|^n$ for $|x|\leq 1$. If $x>1$ then $x^{n^2} = (x^n)^n$ and for large $n$ we will have $|x|^n > 2$.

Comment: Try the ratio test again, or explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

For the ratio test, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{x^{(n+1)^2}}{2^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{2^n}{x^{n^2}}\right\rvert&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lvert x\rvert^{2n+1}}{2}.
\end{align*}
$$
Notably, this limit is $0$ if $\lvert x\rvert<1$, $\frac{1}{2}$ if $\lvert x\rvert=1$, and positive infinity if $\lvert x\rvert>1$. What does that tell you?

Comment: The internal of convergence is [-1,1]

Comment: More precisely, if $x>1$ the sum is $+\infty$ and if $x<-1$ the sum is undefined  because we have an alternate series with increasing ratio.

Comment: @AnneBauval True, but I wasn't claiming that the sum was positive infinity in both cases, but rather that the stated limit of ratios was positive infinity.

Comment: I know. it was just to answer a [slightly more precise question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4579083/386889). More generally, I am curious about how to answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760842), and how to classify the "mode of divergence" of alternate series.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients of this power series are
$$a_k=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2^n}, &\text{if }k=n^2\text{ for some }n\\
0, &\text{else}\end{cases}.$$
So
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}|a_k|^{\frac{1}{k}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{2^n}\right|^{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$$
Thus the radius of convergence is $1$. Also it's trivial that the series converges if $|x|=1$. Hence the interval of convergence is $[-1,1]$.