# Proof that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{x^{n^{2}}}{3^n})$ is divergent and not $\infty$ for x<-1

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is easy to prove that for $x\geq-1$ the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{x^{n^{2}}}{3^n})$ either converges or is +$\infty$. However, I cannot find the answer for $x<-1$. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Use Cauchy-Hadamar formula.

Comment: You can use the ratio test. The series converges if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{x^{(n+1)^2}}{3^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{3^n}{x^{n^2}}\right| = \frac{|x|}3 \lim_{n\to\infty} x^{2n} < 1$$What happens next?

Comment: @user170231 Using the ratio test you get that the limit is +$\infty$ so $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty(|\frac{x^{n^{2}}}{3^n}|)$ =+$\infty$ , which doesnt tell us anything about $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{x^{n^{2}}}{3^n})$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Radius and interval of convergence for $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n^2}}{2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676818/radius-and-interval-of-convergence-for-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracxn2) I think it does, because any of the two hints above, applied in the answers of that duplicate, apply the same way here, and a power series with radius $R$ always [trivially diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth-term_test) outside $[-R,R].$

Answer (score 1):

$x<-1\implies \vert x \vert > 1.\ $ So,

$$ \left\lvert \frac{ x^{n^2} }{ 3^n } \right\rvert > 2 \iff n^2 \log \vert x \vert - n\log 3 > \log 2 $$

$$ \iff n^2 \log \vert x \vert - n\log 3 - \log 2 > 0  $$

$$ \iff \ldots $$

$$ \iff n \geq N \in\mathbb{N}. $$

Since $\ \left\lvert \frac{ x^{n^2} }{ 3^n } \right\rvert > 2\ $ for all $\ n\geq N,\ $ the series $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n^{2}}}{3^n}$ does not converge.

I've left it as an exercise to the reader to find $\ N\ $ in terms of $\ \vert x\vert.$

Comment: Seems to be correct but why it doesn't converge if |$\frac{x^{n^{2}}}{3^n}$| >2

Comment: If $a_n \not\to 0,\ $ then $\ \sum a_n\ $ diverges.

Comment: I think I found a duplicate ;-) (see above). However, the OP here  asked for "and not $\infty$", which is easy to prove but this is neither done in the duplicate nor here. May be we should adopt your philosophy, and add this detail over there?

Comment: Well, both questions are of low quality as the questioner didn't show any effort, so it doesn't really matter...